# How check if shape vector contains a shape with a certain value

Tags: hacklang

```
shape x {
   ?'a' => ?string,
   ?'b' => ?string,

}
```

I have an array of shape x, And I am trying to see if any of the shapes have a value of 'hello' in field 'a'. How can i do so using built in functions?

Comment: Shapes act exactly like arrays from the reading side, except values are typed, and they require a string literal to index them. Are you having a specific difficulty with that shape?

Answer (score 1):

```
function has_hello(vec<shape(?'a' => string, ?'b' => string)> $items): bool {
  foreach ($items as $item) {
    if (Shapes::idx($item, 'a') === 'hello') {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

You can use `Shapes::idx` to get the value of an optional field. If you're looking for helper functions to iterate on arrays, check out the `C\` namespace.